# XSLT ../name() in version 1.0

Tags: xslt, expression, levelup

i wrote as beginner xslt for version 2.0 and it is work

```
    <xsl:template name="ParamOrTpItem">
            <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../name()='or'">
....
```

this template is for displaying of conditions and it is recursive calling. i would like to generate html over python and lxml, so i switched to version 1.0, because it is nessesary for lxml

> `xsl:when : could not compile test expression '../name()='or''`

i can use in test expression syntax like `name()` or `../Atribute` but combination `../name()` is impossible for XSLT 1.0. can you advice me to resolving  this situation, i would like to travers level up for `name()`

3rd party of dll for generating html over python like Saxon work, but is for me impossible
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `name(..) = 'or'` or `../self::or`. Also for Python there is a now a module to use Saxon 9.9 C with Python.